# Find a table row below to highlight it

Tags: jquery, row, highlight

I got checkbox:

```
<input class="_checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
```

And , when I click it:

```
$(function() {
    $('._checkbox').click(function() {
        [..]
    });
});
```

I need to highlight a table row that is below the checkbox.
I've tried with :

```
$(function() {
    $('._checkbox').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings("#table_row").css("background-color", "blue");
    });
});
```

But doesn't work.

I guess I'll have to add some unique IDs, but have no idea how should I read them , etc.

Comment: Can you show us HTML so we can understand what you mean by **table row below checkbox**. Because based on what you've presented you're either having invalid HTML or doing thing completely in the wrong way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean that you next row after the current one with checkbox then define current row and get next:

```
$(function() {
    $('._checkbox').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').next().css("background-color", "blue");
    });
});
```

If you need to hightlight current one:

```
$(function() {
    $('._checkbox').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "blue");
    });
});
```

Comment: One of these two is probably what he's after. +1

Comment: Yep, I didn't get too his phrase: **table row below checkbox**. So I've decided to provide 2 samples.